# Does Putting More AC Transformers In Parallel = More Power?

Tags: electricity

I have two high voltage Microwave Oven Transformers (MOTs) and I need to have more power in my output. Since I don’t have two torn apart MOTs I will not be able to show a diagram for my idea. I can describe it though.

I have 0 Gauge aluminum wire wrapped through the E core of the transformer. I have not modified the transformer body itself by cutting it or damaging it. I have cut one secondary out of the one MOT but not out of the other.

They are both 60 Hz and both use the same load of 1,380 watts.

Then I want to wrap the 0 Gauge wire through the other MOT the same way so that they are both in parallel.

Will this add more power or not?

[image: My SetUp]

Comment: how do you intend to connect the primaries?

Comment: Don't do this. Just...don't.

Comment: Be very very careful of mucking about with microwave transformers unless you have experience dealing with voltages of that level. They can, and will kill you. Looking at your other posts it would seem you're building a high-voltage (>1KV) high-power (>2kW) DC supply for some sort of rail/coilgun (neat project btw). Unless you have some experience designing such high voltage devices I might reconsider your approach.

Comment: @Platytude, as is common with may DIY projects involving microwave oven transofrmers, Scientist Smith YT is removing the factery high voltage secondary and replacing it with his own extra low voltage secondary.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my other posts, and yes I have experience in the high voltage range of 1kV up to 100 kV range. But for this I’m (like Jason said) replacing the secondary winding with high amperage wire to make a low voltage high amperage device.

Comment: I intend to connect the primaries on separate but same phase 20 amp circuits.

Comment: I can give a picture of my set up later today if I can get the time to cut my second transformers secondary winding to give a better understanding of exactly my set up.

Comment: Don't do that primary connection! when you plug one transformer in the other plug becomes live.... it's probably also a code violation.

Comment: @Jason Can you give me schematics as to what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how well matched they are for inductance and more important, coupling factor.

A 1% difference in mutual coupling will amplify circulating currents by 100x more than the load current into a very low resistance.

A 50% difference in inductance will reduce sharing by 50%.

Comment: By inductance do you need the material the transformer is made of?

Comment: yes it's those layers of Silicate coated silicon iron steel called the relative permeability \$\mu _R\$

Comment: It’s a lot of layers to count. I believe the plates on this transformer is not silicon. Because of the look. I believe the plates are high iron. I also know that the inductance is very high and energy transfer is also high. Does this information help?

Comment: read again. I said coated, as each lay must be insulated. They must be identical not just similar.

Comment: @ScientistSmithYT note that he's talking about mismatch of parallel-connected secondaries, NOT about common winding through two transformers, as in your photograph.  (So, any mismatch would appear at the primaries, since only one secondary exists!)     So, measure the primary amps mismatch when the system is under load.  If one xfrmr draws far more current than the other,  perhaps you'll need to add a variable inductor in series with the too-high 120v current, then adjust to balance.  As you thought, that would  then give 2X wattage of a single xfrmr.

Comment: Yes, that is to prevent circulating currents and saturation mainly, power doubler secondary

Answer (score 0):

If you arrange the secondaries in series the voltage will self-balance. If you do not they may be mismatched and you can get a large circulating current

[image: schematic]

Not shown: Transformer cores should be grounded.

If there is a chance of contact. The secondary should be double-insulated or grounded.

So you'll need to re-do both transformer secondaries with half as many turns and then connect those in series.

If you're using a single turn secondary, don't despair. What you can do then is put one wire through half of both transformers, and then the other wire though the other half. After you've done that, then connect those series half-turns in parallel.

On the other hand in 115V land those setups are going to pose a larger than usual load on a typical 115V outlet. Which will prove unsafe if plugged into two 115V outlets. But by connecting the primaries in series and the secondaries in parallel you get something that can safely be connected to a 230V outlet.

[image: schematic]

Not shown: Transformer cores should be grounded.

If there is a chance of contact. The secondary should be double-insulated or grounded.

Comment: Thanks for the circuit diagram and the good and bad circuitry. But I am looking for info on  parallel.

Comment: parallel is best avoided.

Comment: ...except if the primaries are in series,

Comment: I added the picture. The secondary was giving me a hard time to get out.

Comment: that's a series connection.

Comment: @Jason How come it has the same voltage as one transformer? That is why I think it is a parallel connection. If it is series shouldn’t it have a higher voltage than just one transformer?

Comment: it should have higher voltage. are both transformers plugged in?

Comment: Both transformers are plugged in.

Comment: maybe it's a phasing problem. if you're on three phase connecting one of the primaries is backwards would give the missing phase as the sum (ie: same amplitiude)

Comment: That makes sense. But I checked it and they are in phase and connected right. I even had my dad that is an electrician check it and he couldn’t find anything wrong with it. Is there another problem that I don’t know of that could be causing it to do that?

Comment: I can't think of anything.

Comment: Your photo is series connected and should generate a different voltage compared to just one transformer.  Try powering just one transformer (but be very careful of the unused terminals during the test, a 250V filament bulb as a burden resistor is wise) and then also try reverse the phase of one of the primaries to try and find if you do have two matched transformers.  They should provide (almost) double your output voltage.